# ROR: Collection select with with include_blank won't allow nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, collection-select

I have a collection select in my form:

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :area %>
    <%= f.collection_select(:area_id, Area.all, :id, :name, include_blank: "No area.") %>
```

And my model validation has no requirement for an area.

It was my understanding that by using include_blank would allow me to choose nil. However i get a validation error "Area must exist"

EDIT:

Here is the important code in the model:

```
has_many :ratings, dependent: :destroy
has_many :noise_ratings, dependent: :destroy
has_many :statuses, dependent: :destroy
has_many :checkins, dependent: :destroy

has_and_belongs_to_many :features

belongs_to :area
belongs_to :campus

validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: { scope: :campus_id, message: "unique space for each campus." }
validates :description, presence: true
validates :campus_id, presence: true
```

Comment: please add your model to the question

Comment: Are you using rails 5 ?, I kind of remember reading that belongs_to associations are required in rails 5, unless you specify required: false, or something like that, I don't remember.

Comment: I am using rails 5

Comment: Just looked it up you're right! Thank you!!

Comment: ok, so, the fix is to specify belongs_to :area, optional: true, that's in case you want to have that kind of data. It was added to prevent data inconsistencies.

Comment: In Rails 5 `belongs_to` associations require the associated object to be present. See the [discussion about this new feature](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/18233).

Comment: @fanta Write up the answer so you can get interwebz points and someone else down the road can find an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails 5 forces you to set all **belongs_to** associations unless you specify **optional: true**. It was added to prevent data inconsistencies, so, in case you want it to behave like previous rails versions, you just have to change your association to this:

```
belongs_to :area, optional: true
```

Answer (score 1):

In Rails 5 validate is set to true by default. Please check for :optional and :required options on [belongs_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to) documentation for more details.